# Powershell script and regexp filtering

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting, powershell-dsc

Here's the PowerShell snippet:

```
$regex = ".*[A-Z a-z][ \t]{3,}"
$file = 'C:\temp\log\log.json'

Get-Content $file2) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.replace('{"time": "', "").
    replace($regex, "")

} | Out-File $file
```

I tested the regex, and it works on the RegExr site.

2018-01-10T14:37:08981+00:00  WindowsFeature Storage-Services  --> match
 2020-01-10T14:37:08997+00:00  WindowsFeature Storage-Services  --> match
 2020-01-10T14:37:09059+00:00  WindowsFeature Storage-Services  The operation 'Get-WindowsFeature' 
 started: Storage-Services
 2018-01-10T14:37:09934+00:00  WindowsFeature Storage-Services  The operation 'Get-WindowsFeature' succeeded: Storage-Services

The first replacement has been successfully completed, but the second no longer.

Comment: The string method `.replace()` does not work with regex. Why don't you use the Powershell statement `-replace` instead? That works with regex.  ;-) ... and BTW: if you actually want to remove something you can omit the second pair of quotes after the `-replace` statement.

Comment: Great pointers, @Olaf; a note regarding terminology: [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) is a PowerShell _operator_.